How do I speed up drake's optimizers?
I am using Drake's Clarabel optimizer to solve Drake's Graph of Convex Sets(GCS) Trajectory Optimization class. I have added the path length cost and time cost functions to the gcs object. I have added a single cost and two constraints to each vertex (~140 vertices) in the main region. I am planning from a start region to a target region and get a solution within approximately 20 seconds. I have seen examples of solutions in under 1 second and am wondering what I can do to increase the speed of the solvers. I have set h_min=0, h_max=7, and bezier curve order=2. Ideally, my solver should take ~1-5 seconds to solve a single path, but solving in under 1 second would be the most useful for solving multiple cases.
What can I do to increase the speed of the solver?

140 regions is quite high compared to most of our examples. Perhaps you're trying to very exhaustively cover the space?
But another crucial piece of information is how complex each region is? (in what dimension, how many faces?).  Often the complexity comes from having a huge number of faces in the set descriptions.
We've been working through speed-ups for all of them, but more info can help me give the best advice.

I will try to reduce the number of faces and vertices and see what that does to the computational time. I am receiving the features from upstream, so I am limited in the number of vertices I can remove. Just to clarify my understanding, should I use the gcs.AddRegion() for each terrain feature or drake:: ... ::Region main_region.AddVertex() for each terrain feature?
What information would be helpful to share to better describe my problem?

It would definitely be helpful to know the average number of faces on each region, the total number of edges in the graph, and the dimension of the regions.

For example, there are 89 regions to consider in the main region. You have a start subgraph, main subgraph, and a target subgraph. On average, there are 16 faces per feature in the main graph. Edges should be created between any touching regions. The typical solution time is 8 seconds, but I would like it to be closer to 1 second. I have tried several methods to reduce the graph complexity, but nothing to bring the time down to a reasonable range. Any ideas? From your experience, what computation time should I expect to see?
